# Identify Minimum Value from each of 200 samples in R

Tags: r, sampling

I am trying to create 200 samples with mean = 3.5 and SD of 0.25 I do this with the following R Command :

```
set.seed(9)
data1 <- replicate(200, rnorm(10,3.5,0.25), simplify=FALSE)
```

I got data1 having 200 samples of size 10.

Now I want to find the minimum value in each sample. I am not able to figure out how do I do it in R. Please Help

Comment: Take a look at the [apply family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family).

Comment: Try using `lapply`

Comment: `sapply(data1, min)` if you want a vector or `lapply(data1, min)` if you want a list

Comment: @Markus, interestingly `replicate` is a wrapper to `sapply`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's is a tidyverse solution that returns a data frame with the sample ID and minimum value of each sample:

```
library(tidyverse)

maximum.value <- map(data1, min) %>% 
    unlist(recursive = FALSE) %>% 
    enframe()
```

- `map` applies the min function to each element of the data1 list
- `unlist` simplifies the list structure to a vectors
- `enframe` converts the atomic vectures into a two-column data frame

Answer (score 0):

You could turn the list into a data.frame using

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(data1), nrow=200, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

and then calculate the minimum value for each row using the apply function

```
MinumumValues <- apply(df, 1, FUN=min)
```

It returns is a data.frame in which each row is the minimum value of the samples created.